# How to get the extreme Left & Right leaf node using closure table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, closures

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nodes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [Position] [char](1) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
    [Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Closure](
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChildId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PathLength] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Closure] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    [ParentId] ASC,
    [ChildId] ASC )
)
```

What I need to do is to get the extreme right node for a specific node.

Any help on the query to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps add a example data set together with an expected result?

Comment: yes, let's us have three nodes nodeA, nodeB, nodeC so nodeA is the parent, nodeB is the right child and nodeC is the left child. now if i query this data asking for extreme right node for nodeA it should give me back nodeB.

Answer (score 0):

**ASSUMPTIONS**

1. `Nodes.Position` determines the position of a child node under a parent and is unique by parent, not globally.
2. The values of `Nodes.Position` are not hard-coded and not known in advance.
3. If you sort by `Nodes.Position`, the first item is the left one, the last one is the right one.
4. The definition of *extreme* node is that it is a node which you get by taking the left-most or right-most child of a node.

**SOLUTION**

The solution only uses `dbo.Nodes` as I wasn't able to find a solution where traversing the tree depth-first would be easier with the closure table and in your scenario the important `Position` column is on `dbo.Nodes`. You could take parent and child ids from `dbo.Closure` and join on `dbo.Nodes` to get `Position` but that would simply add some unnecessary joins.

The query below is for the extreme right node, to find the left one change the sorting to `ASC`.

```
;WITH
RecCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        1 AS NodeLevel
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                N.Id, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.ParentId ORDER BY N.Position DESC) AS NodeRank
            FROM 
                dbo.Nodes AS N
            WHERE
                N.ParentId = @Parent
        ) AS SQ
    WHERE
        NodeRank = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Id,
        NodeLevel + 1 AS NodeLevel
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                N.Id,
                R.NodeLevel,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.ParentId ORDER BY N.Position DESC) AS NodeRank
            FROM 
                dbo.Nodes AS N
                INNER JOIN RecCTE AS R ON N.ParentId = R.Id
        ) AS SQ
    WHERE
        NodeRank = 1
)
SELECT 
    Id 
FROM 
    RecCTE
WHERE
    NodeLevel IN ( SELECT MAX(NodeLevel) FROM RecCTE )
```

**UPDATE: Nested Sets Solution**

If you're open to changing table structure, I'd suggest looking at nested sets approach for this scenario. For example, if you'd have this table (populated with respect to node positions):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].NestedSets
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    LeftNum int NOT NULL,
    RightNum int NOT NULL,
    PathLength int NOT NULL
)
```

Then finding your extreme left node should be as simple as

```
SELECT
    C.Id
FROM
    dbo.NestedSets AS C
    INNER JOIN dbo.NestedSets AS P
        ON P.LeftNum < C.LeftNum AND P.RightNum > C.RightNum
WHERE
    P.Id = @Parent 
    AND C.LeftNum = C.RightNum - 1
    AND C.LeftNum = P.LeftNum + C.PathLength - P.PathLength
```

The extreme right node:

```
SELECT
    C.Id
FROM
    dbo.NestedSets AS C
    INNER JOIN dbo.NestedSets AS P
        ON P.LeftNum < C.LeftNum AND P.RightNum > C.RightNum
WHERE
    P.Id = @Parent 
    AND C.LeftNum = C.RightNum - 1
    AND C.RightNum = P.RightNum - (C.PathLength - P.PathLength)
```

I'm not sure if in your context closure approach makes more sense that nested sets, but for the purpose of this query the difference is quite dramatic.

Comment: Serge, thanks for your quickly response but i used the closure table to not use recursive CTE so do you suggest to add new column to the closure table that holds the position.

Comment: @salmaahmed I'm not entirely sure what your context is but for the purpose of the query I don't see how position in the closure table will make much sense. It'd still be the position within the parent, right?

Comment: @salmaahmed Please have a look at the updated answer. I think switching to nested sets would make a big difference. Is there any reason you cannot use that?